# facebook, how to automatically get a TEST_USER_1_ACCESS_TOKEN, without hosting a web application

Tags: facebook

I need to create some facebook test users, and set them all friends:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/test_users/

I do as follows:

1. I get an APP_ACCESS_TOKEN:

   https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id={APP_ID}&client_secret={APP_SECRET}&grant_type=client_credentials"
2. I create a few test users

   https://graph.facebook.com/{APP_ID}/accounts/test-users?&access_token={APP_ACCESS_TOKEN}

I get a id, login_url, email and password for each user

that works.

Now I want to tell that TEST_USER_1 and 2 are friends. I should call this, and viceversa:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/{TEST_USER_1_ID}/friends/{TEST_USER_2_ID}?method=post&access_token={TEST_USER_1_ACCESS_TOKEN}
```

**the question is how can I automatically get the TEST_USER_1_ACCESS_TOKEN?**

for points 1 and 2, I used simple http calls (for instance, using `curl`), without hosting a webserver or whatsoever.
can I get the TEST_USER_1_ACCESS_TOKEN without hosting a webserver?

Here it explains the login mechanism: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/login-flow-for-web-no-jssdk/

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id={app-id}&redirect_uri={redirect-uri}&response_type=token
```

but this requires a redirect_uri, so I would need to host a webserver just to get that code.
(or I should manually type that url to the webbrowser, login in with that user, and take the code from the url)

So,
how can I automatically get the TEST_USER_1_ACCESS_TOKEN, without hosting a web application?

Comment: You can have localhost as `redirect_uri` for your application.

Comment: even with this, i still would need to manually go to the web browser, go to facebook.com, and login in the user.

Comment: Yup, that's the only way. You will have to display the dialog box,and login to get the code and work with it

Answer (score 0):

you can just use the test users interface in app settings - click create, set number of test users and then click modify -> select all -> make friends

https://developers.facebook.com/apps/APP_ID/roles